# Using Filezilla with Joomla and GoDaddy

Tags: joomla, filezilla

I have created a a website in my localhost computer using Joomla, and mow I want to launch the site into the web so I bought a domain from GoDaddy.com .

I'm a newbie at this and I was using This Tutorial in order to set up the website.  Now I'm Stuck in the Step 08 Which asks to upload some files into the web host directory.

I used FileZilla as my FTP Client.  When I give the host name and the password, port number as 21 and try to login it says "Connection Timed Out.  Could Not Connect to server."

Please explain how to use the FileZilla and solve the above problem.

Comment: You'll need to provide the URL to the tutorial you're using.

Comment: You might want to look at getting an online host.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hostname try giving ip adress of host

Answer (score 1):

write Ip address of your site in the place of hostname.
It will work.